# Can't wrap my mind around css floats (divs floatup to / around an image) -

Tags: css, image, html, css-float

The image is pulled in, then the posts.  I'd like the posts to float up next to the image and fill the space to the right.  I've tried various combos of the image float/left, the posts float/left or right, display:inline-block on things (I've also pulled the h3 just to muck around with it and it didn't matter).

I have a feeling it has to do with widths of the posts divs, because when I had the first post with very little text it would float up to the vertical version of a thumbnail (that got loaded), but if the post had a full chunk of text, forget it.

So what am I missing.  :)  Danke.

Comment: Put the `h3` tag before the image and set `.homefloat { width: 50%; }`

Comment: @Andy - You don't need to move the `h3` tag at all.

Comment: @Shauna I'm assuming OP wants the header above image, moving the h3 tag is better than using absolute positioning or negative margins to get it there

Comment: @Andy - Fair enough, though I'd note that the OP never mentioned anything about the `h3` that's currently next to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it does have to do with the width of your `homeFloat` divs.

Block level elements will make themselves as wide as their container by default. This will push them down under other containers when floated. In order to make them float next to other items, you need to specify a `width` (or a `max-width`), such that homeFloat + image + padding is equal to or less than the width of the container.

*Edit:* Also, make sure everything is properly wrapped in elements. `<p>` tags will wrap around floated images like you're looking for, so it should be doable with a little reworking of your HTML.

Comment: So there is no real solution to having how ever many divs float up next to the image while the ones that don't make that cut and stay below the image take up the full space below that image.

I was trying to think if all the posts were just 'text' and not inside divs, would that wrap around the image.
I only mentioned the H tag because (and can't remember if I removed it or not) it had a clear:both; on it.

Comment: `clear:both` only works on the elements that are above the element with `clear` on it. And no, there's not a solution with your current setup, at least not without JavaScript. You might want to experiment with your HTML structure to see what does and doesn't wrap how you want (I know plain `<p>` blocks will wrap how you're wanting, for example).

Comment: I went in and changed the html and stripped all the DIVS and put P tags around each post entry and now it is floating up like I wanted (nicely around the dynamic image that is being pulled in).  But it's nice to have someone to chat it out with.  :)  Thanks.

Comment: @KBarnes - Don't forget to mark answers to your question as "accepted" so that people will be more inclined to help you.

Comment: I thought I did as soon as I replied.  I have a big green check mark next to your answer, and a up arrow next to your second reply.

Comment: Yeah, it's there now. I submitted that comment before it registered that you accepted it.